# How does the replaceSubModel function work in OMSimulator Python?

Tags: python, openmodelica

When i am trying to use the function to replace an existing FMU with a new FMU, there are no errors, but the FMU is not getting replaced.

This is my code.

```
from OMSimulator import OMSimulator

oms = OMSimulator()
oms.importFile("sim1.ssp")
oms.replaceSubModel("sim1.Root.VfController", "C:\\Users\\Njssa\\OneDrive - Aalto University\\Master's In Mech\\Master's Thesis\\Open Modelica\MotorSystem\\VfController\\VfController2.fmu",dryRun=True)
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but many Linux tools (like the ones used by OpenModelica  /OMSimulator) don't like spaces and other special characters in path names. Try copying the FMU into a path with short ASCII-only, no accents, no spaces, no symlinks, no subst or network drives.

Comment: Tried it. Still doesn't work